# What is unfiltered_html WordPress user capability?

Tags: wordpress

I am using and customizing WordPress `bbpress` plugin, and I see that `WordPress user capability` returns `unfiltered_html` .

What does `unfiltered_html` mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make the code parts of it more evident, in order to make it easier for Stack Overflow users to identify the question, and thus help you - please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [right in the Codex](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#unfiltered_html). `unfiltered_html`:

> Allows user to post HTML markup or even JavaScript code in pages, posts, comments and widgets.
>
> Note: Enabling this option for untrusted users may result in their posting malicious or poorly formatted code.
>
> Note: In WordPress Multisite, only Super Admins have the unfiltered_html capability.